# Use Enum.values in with generic class extending Enum

Tags: java, generics, enums

I am trying to initialise a generic class with all the availables values from an Enum. HEre is how I would like it to work:

```
public class MyClass<E extends Enum<E>> {

    E[] choices;

    public MyClass() {
        choices = E.values();
    }
```

However, the call to `E.values` is not accepted in Eclipse saying that this method is undefined for this E.

Using this constructor instead is accepted, but requires the caller to provide the values:

```
public MyClass(E[] e) {
    choices = e;
}
```

In the documentation I found:

> Java programming language enum types are much more powerful than their
>   counterparts in other languages. The enum declaration defines a class
>   (called an enum type). The enum class body can include methods and
>   other fields. The compiler automatically adds some special methods
>   when it creates an enum. For example, they have a static values method
>   that returns an array containing all of the values of the enum in the
>   order they are declared.

Is there a way to workaround this issue ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your best option is probably to pass a `Class` of the desired enum to the constructor. (See how an [`EnumMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) is constructed for instance.)

You can then use `clazz.`[`getEnumConstants`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants%28%29)`()` to get hold of the constants.

Answer (score 3):

Your first code snippet doesn't work because of how Generics is implemented in Java, and due to a phenomenon known as [type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4399623/473637). Because of this, the JVM will have no idea what the type of `E` is when your program is executing.

You could probably do something like this in `MyClass`'s constructor:

```
public MyClass(E type) {
    choices = type.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants();
}
```

Comment: I believe this has nothing to do with type erasure. The cause of the problem is that the method `public static E[] values()` is not a method present in the `java.lang.Enum` class. [The Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2) explains that this method, though, is synthetically generated for all enums. So, in my opinion, the method is present in any concrete reference of a enum, but not in the enum class itself.

Comment: If you have two classes, `public class A {
 
 public static void test(){}

}` and `public class B<A> {
 
 public B() {A.test();}

}`, the line A.test() is still a compile time error, because at runtime, the compiler would not know the type of A without it being explicitly defined, say as a parameter of type A passed into the constructor.

Comment: @Jeshrun  No it's not. It's a compile-time error because in your declaration `class B<A>` the `A` is an unbounded type argument. The `A` in this declaration has nothing to do with the class `A`. Would it compile if you declare it as `class B<T extends A>` where the declaration has no obvious ambiguities between the type parameter and the class name and by using a reference to T?

Comment: @Jeshrun I am not arguing with the fact that you cannot directly access members of a type parameter `T`. But you could acccess them through a valid reference of type `T` if you had one. Which proves your type erasure theory as bogus in my opinion.

Comment: @Jeshrun Bottom line, in the question `E` is a type parameter, not a class; and as you well pointed out the reason why we cannot directly access `E` is because the type information related to it is discarded. But you could perfectly invoke static methods in refrences of `E`. In the question we could invoke `choices.valueOf(...)` which is a static method of the class `Enum`. However, the reason why we cannot invoke `choices.values()` it's because it does not exist in the `Enum` class. It is however synthetically generated for every concrete enum by the compiler.

Comment: Ok you are saying it is bogus in one comment, and that you agree with it in the next. But I still disagree with the invoking static methods on a generic type. Even if the generic type is a derived type with the parent type containing static methods, the vm would still have no clue what the type of the parent is at runtime, unless there is a reference of said type lying around.